# Retrieving ulong from Sqlite relsults in NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, ulong

I've got some hash values (as ulong) saved to a Sqlite database by a console application. Now I'd like to retreive those values inside a Windows Store App, unfortunately I get a NotSupportedException saying "Don't know how to read System.UInt64". Can't I use ulong values in my database? 
The DB is populated and the hash-field does seem to be ulong, at least thats what Database .NET tells me.

Comment: what is the database field-type`?

Comment: I created it as ulong and thats also what Database .NET shows me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite's integers have 64 bits, [but are signed](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#storageclasses).

You should cast your hash values to/from `long`.

Comment: casting to long I would loose one bit, right? Some of my hashes do need almost the full size of ulong.

Comment: Nvm, I realized that I still can save the same amount of numbers. But what happens to values that are higher then what long can save? Will those become negative?